# Why do two potentials of a game only differ by a constant?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Can someone explain to me the proof on page 7/20 of the original paper about potential games ([https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~mansour/sem-game-02-03/monderer-potential-96.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Emansour/sem-game-02-03/monderer-potential-96.pdf))?

It is about why two potentials of a game G can only differ by a constant.

Comment: Lemma 2.7 is a quick consequence of lemma 2.1, which is said by the author to have an obvious proof.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how we can follow from formula `H` that `P1(y) - P2(y) = c`?

Comment: @AlexM. Seems like it's referring to equation 2.1, not Lemma 2.1.

Comment: @usul: Indeed, I believe you are right. In any case, lemma 2.7 is trivial.

Comment: @AlexM. Not for me, anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it looks like to me: to get $H(y)$, we change strategy profile $z$ into $y$ one player at a time, summing the changes in utility. For any exact potential $P$ (which is actually equation 2.2 with weights $1$), each change in utility is equal to $P(a_{i-1}) - P(a_{i})$. This is a telescoping sum, so $H(y) = P(y) - P(z)$. This didn't depend on which exact potential $P$ we chose, so $P_1(y) - P_1(z) = P_2(y) - P_2(z)$ for all $y$. In other words $P_1(y) = P_2(y) + c$ where $c = P_1(z) - P_2(z)$.

Comment: How do you conclude from P2(y) - P2(z) to P1(y) = P2(y) + c? What I mean is - how did you move from z and y to just y?

Comment: Rearrange $P_1(y) - P_1(z) = P_2(y) - P_2(z)$ as $P_1(y) - P_2(y) = P_1(z) - P_2(z)$. Choose some arbitrary $y$ and call $c = P_1(y) - P_2(y)$. It follows that $P_1(z) - P_2(z) = c$ for every $z$, i.e. $P_1 = P_2 + c$.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you so much!